# Connecting ActiveMQ Artemis and Amazon MQ brokers

Tags: activemq-artemis, amazon-mq

I am trying to connect an ActiveMQ Artemis broker with an Amazon MQ broker to create a hybrid architecture. I have tried connecting ActiveMQ with Amazon MQ, and I could achieve it by using "network connectors" in the `activemq.xml` file and it worked fine.

For connecting Amazon MQ and ActiveMQ Artemis brokers I have added below shown "bridge configuration" and the "connector" to the Artemis `broker.xml` file

```xml
<bridges>
    <bridge name="my-bridge">
        <queue-name>factory</queue-name>
        <forwarding-address>machine</forwarding-address>
        <filter string="name='rotor'"/>
        <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>             
        <user>admin</user>
        <password>12345678</password>
        <static-connectors>                   
            <connector-ref>netty-ssl-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
    </bridge>
</bridges>

<connectors> 
    <connector name="netty-ssl-connector">ssl://b-...c-1.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:61617?sslEnabled=true;</connector>
</connectors>
```

I'm getting an exception: **ssl schema** not found.

So I'm trying to understand whether connecting the ActiveMQ Artemis and Amazon MQ brokers is same as connecting ActiveMQ Activemq and Amazon MQ brokers (i.e by changing the configuration in the `broker.xml` file)? If so, what are the changes I need to make to the above shown configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveMQ Classic (i.e. 5.x) and Amazon MQ use the OpenWire protocol to establish connections in a network of brokers. ActiveMQ Artemis supports clients using the OpenWire protocol. However, ActiveMQ Artemis uses its own "core" protocol for bridges and clustering. Therefore you won't be able to create a bridge from ActiveMQ Artemis to ActiveMQ Classic or Amazon MQ since those brokers don't understand the Artemis "core" protocol.

The `ssl` schema is used by OpenWire clients, not "core" clients. That is why you can't create an Artemis bridge using it.

If you want to integrate Artemis and Amazon MQ I'd recommend something like Camel or even possibly the JMS bridge that ships with Artemis. You can see examples of both in [this example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/sub-modules/inter-broker-bridge/artemis-jms-bridge) which ships with Artemis.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Adding further to my question, is there any possibility to connect the brokers(Artemis and AmazonMQ) using Apache Camel,JMS bridging or anyother??.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!